# Simple Facebook app, no permissions but add abuse protection/user tracking?

Tags: facebook, permissions

Ok so I am developing my first facebook app, it is a very simple voting system everything is going to be on my db and in facebook using an iframe. I do not need to access user information or post to a wall for them or anything like that. I do however need to track users to prevent them from abusing the voting system. I am not sure but is there a unique identifier I can store from the user without requesting permissions? Ie. user token, or id or w.e.

I read the basic information portion of the facebook permissions but I can't understand whether that is data given without permissions request or after the permissions request prompt.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/  (basic information section)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, these answers were not helpful. So through trial and error we found that even basic information like the facebook user id, as well as any other unique data are not accessible in any fashion without sending the user to a permissions request to accept the application.

Answer (score 0):

When you set up your app like you said and users use your app you will be able to acces their id and some other stuff but the id is all that you need. So its the data without permission.

Comment: This answer is contradictory to my experiences and to other stackoverflow questions (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305427/simple-facebook-app-no-permissions-but-add-abuse-protection-user-tracking): Because of privacy issues it isn't possible to access a user identifier without any permissions. Or a I missing something?

Comment: yeah this doesn't work. There is no possible identifier that can be taken without permission from the user, the only data you are able to obtain is very basic and vague without it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend accesing their User ID and using that as a tracking method within the database.